# text-shadow effect on width of div?

Tags: css

How does the text-shadow effects the width of a div? After adding text-shadow to my design, it has disturbed the width of the div.

Please see the demo, if you remove the text-shadow from the container, you will see both div's (left and right, fit inside the container div, but with the text-shadow it does not fit (in firefox).

http://jsfiddle.net/88ruZ/

Comment: Please, show your HTML and CSS...

Comment: @Luca - text-shadow should not affect your layout in any way, but we will need to see an example - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Myles Gray: It's a known issue in some browsers. I speak from personal experience.

Comment: @BoltClock - Do you know specifically which browsers so I may experiment with it?

Comment: @Myles Gray: I can't remember, I probably saw it on Firefox. I was applying `text-shadow` to everything including `body` and a horizontal scrollbar was produced.

Comment: Looks grand here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/GA9x2/ FF4.0b10

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle link in original post, please see that. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucka - Looks great in FF4 - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17927147/StackOverflow/Screen%20shot%202011-02-10%20at%2013.35.27.png - What browser/version are you experiencing this in?

Comment: I'm using FF 3.6.13. No support for that?

Answer (score 0):

I set the width of both left and right classed divs to 190px. That worked for me, you can also set the overflow to hidden, which will retain the dashed border w/o changing the widths of the child divs, but i'm guessing you want to have overflow on.

Comment: Yeah, I know by decreasing the width, it solves for firefox but that looks ugly in other browsers. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/88ruZ/2/

Have to add

```
padding:4px;
```

To `.container` class.